# Check if String starts with column value with best performance

Tags: sql-server

I currently have this table (myTable) in my database:

```
user             start
----------------------------
Adam             12345
Alex             123
Benny            2345
```

In my program, I accept a string from user, eg: 12345678

My objective is to select out the row where user input starts with myTable.Start

```
-- For example, it would be great to have something like:

select * from myTable where "12345678".startsWith(start)

-- and returns me Adam, 12345 & Alex, 123
```

As of now I'm using

```
select user, start
from myTable where charindex(start, "12345678") = 1 
order by start desc
```

which does the job, but in absolute terrible performance, myTable row count is about near a million, I'm not sure if indexing start would help as I'm not doing a direct compare in this case.

Does anyone know a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select user, start
from myTable 
where '12345678' like start+'%'
order by start desc
```

Also add an index to the column start.

Comment: This probably won't improve performance. *Instead* of a prefix search, all rows have to be searched to construct the argument, then match against the string. This isn't a range search so can't use an index

Comment: In general, applying any sort of operation on a column prevents the query optimizer from using indexes, precisely because new values have to be calculated for each row.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, but (*where start LIKE "12345678%"*) will not return the result itself

Answer (score -1):

You should use the pattern matching operator, [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator AND add an index to the column, eg:

```
select user, start
from myTable where start LIKE "12345678%"
order by start desc
```

Without the index performance will be as bad as before - the server would have to check all rows for matches.

With an index, the operation becomes a range search: rows where start is greater or equal to `12345678` but less than the next higher string lexically (`12345679`). Range searches can use indexes and load process only the matching lines

**EDIT**

Oops, missed that the query tries to do the opposite - find rows that can act as prefixes to a string. This can't be accelerated with indexes because it's equivalent to

```
"someconstantvalue" LIKE start +'%'
```

This *has* to generate a new value for each row before matching, so can't use any indexes

Comment: But, my 'start' is always shorter than user input, where '12345678%' is definitely not returning '12345'

Comment: What you ask is equivalent to creating a new pattern for each row and matching it to a string. This can't take advantage of indexes.